An irreducible space with more than one generic point
I'm asked to give an example of an irreducible space which has more than one generic point.
Can someone check if my example is valid?
Consider the 4-point space $X=\{a,b,c,d\}$, with open sets: $\emptyset$, $X$, $A=\{a,b,c\}$, $B=\{b,c,d\}$ and $C=\{b,c\}$.
I claim $b$ and $c$ are generic points.
Is this correct? Is this even a topological space?

Yes, it is correct. Since $b$ and $c$ are in every open set (except for the empty set), they are dense.

This is certainly correct, but you could also have a simpler example: just take the trivial topology on two points, say.

@DavidGao nice.
